# Use LINQ to convert comma separated strings in a table into a distinct collection of values

Tags: c#, linq

I'm working through this [MVC3 tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-mvc3-part1-cs) and have entered the genre of a film as a comma separated string.

In part 6 we take the genres from the table to populate a drop down list.

I'd like to populate the drop down list with a distinct collection of single genres but I just can't get it to work.

This is what the tutorial suggest as a start point

```
var GenreLst = new List<string>();

var GenreQry = from d in db.Movies
                   orderby d.Genre
                   select d.Genre;
GenreLst.AddRange(GenreQry.Distinct());
```

... and this is where I'd got to

```
var GenreLst = new List<string>();

var GenreQry = (from d in db.Movies
                orderby d.Genre
                select d.Genre ).Select(s=>s.Split(','))
                .Distinct();

GenreLst.AddRange( GenreQry );
```

Comment: "I can't get it to work" is not a question. If your code doesn't compile, give the error message. If it doesn't do what you expect, show what it does and what you expect it to do.

Comment: I'm sorry. I wasn't able to get it to compile either but supplied code to show what I was trying to do. I have now implemented the solution suggested by @SaeedAmiri with a little twist. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Linq2Sql doesn't know `s.Split(',')` method, so it should throw an exception, you can do this:

```
var GenreQry = (from d in db.Movies
             orderby d.Genre                 
             select d.Genre ).Distinct().ToList(); 

GenreLst.AddRange( GenreQry.SelectMany(x=>x.Split(',')).Distinct());
```

**about above code:**
When calling `ToList()` in the end of query, your data will be fetched and your query in fact is list, 
in second part, `SelectMany` flats separated strings as a IEnumberable of strings.

**Edit:** Also in first part you can call `.AsEnumerable()` instead of `.ToList()` for fetching data, it seems better way.

Comment: Thanks. I had to tweak the brackets to get the output I wanted and ended up with "GenreLst.AddRange( GenreQry.SelectMany(x=>x.Split(',')).Distinct() );"

Comment: @TeamWild, I understand that and edit it, I wrote it in IE and i didn't see brackets are not match:)

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to to the sort or `Distinct` in the initial query because you have to do it all over again after you do the `Split`.

Comment: @Gabe, why fetch extra information from DB? when at last you want remove them, for performance issue is better prevent that, if data size is large, transfer of them is more time consuming job than calling distinct, also sql will be run fast enough.

Comment: @Saeed: Fair enough, but why sort the data before it comes back? Why copy it to a `List`?

Comment: @Gabe, About Sort it was copy past from `OP`'s sample! but it doesn't affect performance of converted query, and about List, Ok you say do `query.AsEnumerable`? yes it's better option. but I see OP seems to be new in linq2sql and if I say `ToList` it's very sensible to say how to fetch data from db, again because we have data transfer here there isn't performance buttle neck (ToList vs AsEnumerable).

Comment: In my final code I have removed the orderby and the Distinct() in the initial query

Comment: @TeamWild, Distinct in first query is better to be.

Comment: The Distinct in the first query will only remove duplicates where the whole string has already been detected. e.g. "Action, Sci-Fi, Thriller" and "Action, Thriller, SciFi" will produce 2 rows where my DDL only wants the 3 distinct values "Action", "Thriller" and "Sci-Fi". It's swings and roundabouts really and I appreciate your help.

Comment: @TeamWild, Yes by this, prevents from fetching extra data from DB, most important part in communication with DB is use smallest data transfer, ditinct runs fast enough in sql server, but when you loading extra data it's more slower than running distinct.

Answer (score 1):

In case you find the SelectMany syntax a bit confusing, consider the following (which compiles into a select many method call under the covers but I find easier to read):

```
var GenreQry = (from d in db.Movies.AsEnumerable() 
                from s in d.Split(',')
                select s)
               .Distinct()
               .OrderBy(s => s);
```

Comment: As Saeed mentioned in a comment to his post, it might make sense to put a `Distinct` before the `AsEnumerable` so as to limit the amount of data returned from the DB, then have `Distinct` again before sorting.